# Acceleration along a 2D plane

Tags: trigonometry, physics

It's been a long time since I've done trig, and I never new it very well. I have a problem I don't know how to solve.

I have an object on a 2D plane that I want to move. I have this objects x and y coordinates, I also have it's velocity, and the angle of the velocity in radians.

How can I take this information and calculate velocity long the X axis and Y axis. I.E., how can I convert the angle and velocity to the delta of X and Y?

Comment: Sounds like a case of using parametric equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$v_x = v\cdot \cos(\theta)$

$v_y = v\cdot \sin(\theta)$